# Call angular service in another js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have some javascript and html files: `User.js`, `index.html`, `Door.js`

I want use any function in `User.js` file.

- [My user.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auBBU.png)
- [My door.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rerGT.png)

I call `getUserInfo` in `user.Js` from `Door.js` file in function
`doorApplicationLoginPage.service`

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UserServiceProvider <- UserService <- PerioMainController

```
var doorApplicationLoginPage = angular.module("PerioLoginPage", []);

doorApplicationLoginPage.service('UserService', function () {

    this.getUserInfo = function () {
        alert("getUserInfo");
    }

    this.reLoginUser = function () {
        alert("reLoginUser");
    }

});


var doorApplication = angular.module("PerioDoorApplication", []);

doorApplication.controller("PerioMainController", function ($scope, $http, $sce, UserService) {


    UserService.getUserInfo();

});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting a `service` which is not referenced to your `module`.

See:

The *UserService* `service` is referenced in *PerioLoginPage* `module`
The *PerioMainController* `controller` is referenced in *PerioDoorApplication* `module`.

You've got either to:

1. **reference the service in the same module** as your controller.
2. **inject the module** where service is referenced to the module where controller is referenced.

Comment: I disagree, he could use a "dependency" from the other module

Comment: You're right. This might happen if he would inject the module where service is referenced to the module where controller is referenced. Thanks for the reply. I am editing right forward.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I can see you have two modules Periodicloginpage and periodicdoorapplication. So two services are defined in two modules. So you have to put the Periodicloginpage as dependency of periodicdoorapplication.

```
var doorApplication = angular.module("PerioDoorApplication", ["PerioLoginPage"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments you have two things to do at least:

You need to return the functions you want to use from the service (`UserService`):

```
return{
    getUserInfo: getUserInfo, 
    reLoginUser: reLoginUser
};
```

Your module needs to reference the one the service is defined on:

```
angular.module('PerioDoorApplication', ['PerioLoginPage']);
```

And in your 'PerioMainController', a better way to write it would be:

```
doorApplication.controller('PerioMainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', 'UserService', 
    function($scope, $http, $sce, UserService){
        [...]
    }
]);
```